# angularjs nested controller does not receive injected service

Tags: angularjs

I clearly do not understand the scope issues that I sense must be at play here. Despite having read quite a bit about scope in angularjs, and seeing it work as expected in many cases.

But here I have 2 nested controllers:

```
MainController [can inject RepositoryService]
 --> ChallengeController [cannot successfully inject RepositoryService]
    --> SingleChallengeController [cannot successfully inject RepositoryService]
 --> PlayerController [can inject RepositoryService]
```

MainController is instantiated via the $routeProvider setup in app.js:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

And here is the app declaration:

```
...
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="m" class="section app-viewport" ng-view=""  ng-keydown="keyPress($event);"></div>
...
```

Meanwhile the other 3 controllers are specified inline in main.html like so:

main.html:

```
    <div id="viewport" viewport ng-hide="isPhone && isLandscape" class="section main">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div main-panel-row-maximize-height class="row main-panel-row">
          <div class="main-panel">
            <div class="row">
              <div id="challenge-options-results" challenge-panel-init class="challenge-option-results display-visible" >
                <section ng-controller="ChallengeController" class="challenge-container">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                  <div ng-controller="SingleChallengeController"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="display-hidden" id="controls-and-badges">
    <div id="readout" ng-controller='PlayerController'  class="balance">
    <span class="readout-label balance">data</span><hr class="balance-separator">
      <span class="amount" ng-bind="currData">$NaN</span>
    </div>
...
```

I am attempting to inject the service ('RepositoryService') into these controllers using the 'constructor' like so:

```
var challengeControllers = angular.module('challengeControllers', []);

challengeControllers.controller('ChallengeController', ['$scope',  function($scope,  eventBusService, RepositoryService) {
...
```

This way of injecting works fine for MainController and PlayerController, but not the other two.

Here is the constructor for the service I want to inject:

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('RepositoryService', []);

serviceModule.factory("RepositoryService", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope, $http) {
```

Is there anything obvious I am missing that suppresses what appears to me to be logical behavior associated with dependency injection?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: No error, it silently continues to completion of all codepaths. However, I was not able to see the service's object passed in via injection (it was undefined). Very strange, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your controller definition like this:

```
challengeControllers.controller('ChallengeController', ['$scope', 'eventBusService', 'RepositoryService', function($scope,  eventBusService, RepositoryService) {
```

It seems like you forgot to add `eventBusService` and `RepositoryService` in the array arguments here.

By the way, if you don't have the need to get this code obfuscated in production, just don't mess with explicitly named injectables and write like this:

```
challengeControllers.controller('ChallengeController', function($scope,  eventBusService, RepositoryService) {
```

Comment: Thank you @artch - I had tried that at one point, after your reminder tried it again. Still, no joy: the service reference was undefined, and there was nothing I could do in the controller to use it. But a quick test of your second remark resulted in success!! How surprising, but in leaving out the strings as a way of naming injectables, the injection worked as expected and I now have access to the Repository service in the controller as needed.  Not sure why but it works. Would be good to be able to minify the code at some point, so any more insight would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you changed RepositoryService factory definition (your example contains a mistake with $http injecting there as well)? Any errors in console?

Comment: I did change it, it now looks like:
var repoServiceModule = angular.module('RepositoryService', []);

repoServiceModule.factory("RepositoryService", function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
...
which was your suggestion I believe. Works perfectly. I will try explicitly named injectables at some point, tho its tempting to just move on with the working code...